# Move/Migration to new web server

Tags: webserver, migration, plesk

We have a web server with about 20 websites hosted one with some other software like Plesk 10, MS SQL SERVER and some certificate for iOS push notification.

This is a dedicated window based server with peer1.

Is there an easy way by which we can move all the website & related database and other configuration to new web server with similar OS.

Comment: Although the question was for Linux, my answer [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34890/how-do-i-migrate-web-files-from-a-plesk-8-installation-on-a-slaved-hdd-to-a-pl/49010#49010) should still be helpful. I'm not sure if they still offer free migration assistance with new licenses, but you could contact their sales team to ask. Their Migration Tool makes upgrading pretty easy, though you _might_ have to add the certificate for iOS push notifications in manually.

Comment: Your reply seems to be more in line with Plesk or it is also at OS level

Comment: Not sure I follow. The Migration Tool will migrate everything that Plesk uses, including hosting accounts, content/user data, configurations, databases, etc... The new Plesk server will be setup just like the old one was. If you meant to somehow setup a server OS without Plesk, then you'd need to do all the setup and copying manually (which I don't recommend since as my answer points out, Plesk uses some unique ways to store configurations and data that would be difficult to figure out).